# Add Drop down list filtering to grid view which is using a stored procedure

Tags: c#, gridview, webforms, updatepanel

I have a grid view populated using a stored procedure. I want to implement filtering to some columns using a drop-down list. Normally i will have 4 drop down lists for 4 columns to filter.

What I tried is:

1. Created a stored procedure to populate unique values for the dropdown list
2. I added the event `onselected` index change to the dropdown so as when the value change the gridview is repopulated based on the value selected but the event is not triggered here

Both my gridview and dropdown list is found inside an update panel which normally will prevent postback. I added a trigger bind to dropdown list control but nothing happens.

Can you advice please how to proceed and if there is any other more efficient way for this scenario please?

````
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="dptest" 
             OnSelectedIndexChanged="dptest_OnSelectedIndexChanged" />
        <asp:GridView ID="testID" runat="server" CellPadding="3" 
             BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px">
            <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066"/>
            <HeaderStyle Width="100px" BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"/>
            <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left"/>
            <RowStyle Width="100px" ForeColor="#000066"/>
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"/>
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1"/>
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#007DBB"/>
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9"/>
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#00547E"/>
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```
````

Answer (score 1):

I only needed to add AutoPostBack="True" for the drop-down list and it worked perfectly.